# The import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowViewAction cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I can not figure out what I am missing solve this import error.  I have org.eclipse.ui_3.107.0.v20150507-1945.jar included in my build path, but it does not seem to be what is required.  I've tried including all the other org.eclipse.ui.* jar files in my build path but none seem to be resolving the import error.  Does any one know what is needed for this?

I'm a relatively new java developer, but have run into the "The import * cannot be resolved" quite a bit and the only way I've found to fix it, if it can't be auto resolved with eclipse's quick fix, is to try and guess what jar needs to be added to the build path.  Is there a more reliable method or is trial and error what it comes down to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **internal** class (the package name includes 'internal'). You should not be trying to use it. Internal classes are often created / changed / deleted without warning between Eclipse releases.

See [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) for more information about the Eclipse API.

This particular action existed in Eclipse 3.x but is no longer present in Eclipse 4. The action essentially calls `IWorkbenchPage.showView`, you will have to write your own action to do the same.